# How to Deploy Java EE Project which reference external JAR files in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, shared-libraries, war, jdeveloper

I have a web application which consist of JSP pages, Servlet and Consumes Web Services.
It also references apache axis and excel libraries.
Now I want to deploy my application directly in Weblogic server
How do i do that.Whcih archive shud i make WAR or JAR??
ALso how to ensures that it covers all the referenced libraries.
I have made my application in Jdeveloper, but I dont want to deploy it using Jdevelper..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would package my solution as a .war file, containing all dependent .jar files.

That way your solution is self-contained. You can deploy to an app server containing other apps with their own versions of your libraries (dependent or developed). If you put the dependent jars directly into the app server (as you can do), then you're forcing those versions on all applications deployed, and that could well cause you grief.

The downside is that your developed .war file can become sizable. It's not normally a major problem, and I wouldn't worry about it until it's identified as an issue.

Comment: Can u tell me how exactly to include my libraries while creating a WAR fellow.I asked a guy he said create alib folder then in the manifest file give the entries of ur libraries or jar files...I did not understand a word of it.Can u plz explain step by step..

Answer (score 0):

A JAR-file cannot contain a JAR-file, so that option is out. Since you mention JSPs and servlets a WAR would seem the appropriate option, although an EAR with a WAR and several JARs could also be a way forward...

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Consider a WAR with your JAR files in WEB-INF/lib. Or, create an EAR with APP-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I feel a need to avoid confusion here by expanding this answer: the EAR way of doing things can help when you want to maintain library consistency among multiple modules (such as multiple wars using the exact same version of a web framework). You can still put jars in individual war modules even when deploying as an EAR to keep them isolated.